# Selenium Python : Is this code right?

Tags: python, selenium

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from commonPages.LoginPage import LoginPage
from util.InitialSetUp import InitSetup
i = InitSetup()
chrome_options = i.close_popup()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
log = LoginPage(driver)
log.nav_login_page()
class Test_User_Profile:
def test_required_fields_are_not_empty(self):
    time.sleep(2)
    profile_link = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'user-dropdown-button')
    profile_link.click()

    user_profile_link = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'user-profile-menu-item')
    user_profile_link.click()

    all_fields = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'input')
    for field in all_fields:
        value_of_field = field.get_attribute('value')
        if value_of_field not in '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]':
            # print(value_of_field)
            length = len(value_of_field)
            # Assert all required fields are filled out
            assert length > 0

def test_required_fields_are_displayed(self):
    all_fields_labels = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, '_2H4nTeLi38d1fmjX5_VWUV')
    empty = []
    for field_labels in all_fields_labels:
        value_of_field = field_labels.text
        if value_of_field not in '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]':
            # print(value_of_field)
            length = len(value_of_field)
            # Assert all required fields are displayed
            assert length > 0
            empty.append(value_of_field)
            # print(empty)
    assert empty == ['name', 'job title', 'email', 'phone', 'location']

# # Close modal
# close_btn = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'close-profile-button')
# close_btn.click()

# # Close browser
# driver.close()
```

The above code sometimes fail to run, and sometimes passes. I am not getting if this is right?

When it fails it gives an error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"close-profile-button"}
(Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591(62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Even though the locator "close-profile-button" is present on the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpage probalby hasnt fully loaded yet, so you need to wait to click the button.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


wait = WebDriverWait(driver,60)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'close-profile-button'))) 

close_btn = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'close-profile-button')
close_btn.click()
```

Comment: This doesn't work, gives an error message at , *wait*

Comment: Was it just improper formatting? I did forget a few things, like parenthesis. About to update. What is the error message?

Comment: `Test_User_Profile.py:52: in Test_User_Profile                                   
 element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME, 'close-profile-button'))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: I figured it out, added an extra () to it, like this: 

`element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'close-profile-button')))`

Comment: But my main concern is if my program is right? 
I tried debugging it, it first checks the `close_btn` and then tries to enter the class. 
Something is wrong!